# Terminal command to move all loose files into a directory with the file name

Tags: macos, finder, command-line, script

I have a folder containing thousands of files and directories. I would like to move all the files that are not contained in a sub directory into a directory and name it the file name, while leaving the files already inside of directories alone, ie:

- create 'newdir'
- move 123.mp4 into 'newdir'
- change name 'newdir' to '123'
- repeat

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/234719/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Command

This command was tested in a bash shell.

```
for x in *;do if [[ -f $x ]];then mkdir newdir;mv "$x" newdir/.;mv newdir "${x%.*}";fi;done
```

### Explanation

The code shown below is not necessary commands you can execute. Rather, what is shown is an explanation of various parts of the code shown above.

Loop through all file names in current directory.

```
for x in *;do ... done
```

Only do regular files. (Skip the directories.)

```
if [[ -f $x ]];then ... fi;
```

Make new directory `newdir`.

```
mkdir "newdir";
```

Move file `x` to new directory `newdir`.

```
mv "$x" newdir/.;
```

Rename `newdir` to the name of the desired new directory. (Set `newdir` to file name `x` after removing the last `.` and all characters that follow.)

```
mv newdir "${x%.*}";
```

### Comments

If the desired directory already exists, then the `newdir` folder (containing the file) will be moved to the desired directory. For example, if the file `123.mp4` and directory `123` both already exist, then file `123.mp4` will end up in `123/newdir`. You can test to see if this occurred by entering the command given below.

```
find . -name newdir
```

For example, if `123/newdir/123.mp4` existed, then the follow output would appear.

```
./123/newdir
```

Answer (score 0):

Limitations:

- **Doesn't** work if you have any file with no extension. <sup>1</sup>
- Exception handling must be added in case a directory already exists.
- Worked on Mojave.  Python 3.7.3, but the posts listed below often don't mention their versions either.
- Did not post on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).
- `#%%` are for VSCode's Jupyter extension.

```py
#%%
import os

# %%
source = "/Users/me/Desktop/folder" # notice the missing last "/"
filenames = next(os.walk(source))[2]
filenames = [ x for x in filenames if not ".DS_Store" in x]
#%%
dirpaths = [os.path.splitext(file)[0] for file in filenames]

# %%
def making(directory,source=source):
   directory = os.path.join(source,directory+"/")
   os.makedirs(directory)

a = [making(directory) for directory in dirpaths]     #list comprehension could be faster than loops.

# %%

def movingfiles(onefile, source=source):
   os.rename(source + "/" + onefile, source + "/" + os.path.splitext(onefile)[0] + "/"  + onefile ) 

b = [movingfiles(onefile) for onefile in filenames]       #useless list again.
```

Sources in order of need:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541390/extracting-extension-from-filename-in-python
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/how-can-i-safely-create-a-nested-directory
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204782/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-a-directory-or-regular-file-in-python
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443871/cut-and-paste-a-file-or-directory-in-python
- <sup>1</sup> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59353082/os-makedirs-wrongly-catches-extension-less-files-for-directory-on-macos

Comment: I'm not all that fluent in Python, but you probably could work around the "Doesn't work if you have any file with no extension" constraint by adding some logic to the function where you call `os.rename`.

Comment: Also, your function names don't really help in making the code understandable.

Comment: That part is documented in last link on SO and limitation comes from directory making, which I shortened the length of, by making it with the file name directly instead of using an intermediate name.

Comment: Ah, right, you create all the subdirectories first (with `func`) and then do the move with `funct` (did I already mention that your function names don't help :-)). Anyway, I would aim for a solution where you only have to process the list of files once and then handle all the special cases (including creation of directories) within the function called for each file.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/234719/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `find` to avoid the typical problems with filenames containing spaces and other whitespace characters:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name '.DS_Store' -exec bash -c '
    t="${1:2}";
    mkdir FluffyBird;
    mv "$t" FluffyBird/
    mv FluffyBird "${t%.*}"' _ {} \;
```

Substitute `FluffyBird` with whatever string which isn't a filename in the folder already.